# How can I use the Add Product form as content in the main menu?

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce to add products to my site.
I would like to use the Add Products form as content in the main menu to make it more user-friendly to edit.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

*Admin > Structure > Menus > Main Menu > Add link*

- Title: Add product
- Path: admin/commerce/products/add/product

Keep in mind, that is for admins to create backend products for the inventory, not front end product displays.

It will also only be generated for admins with the relevant permissions.

To add a link for creating a frontend product display, the path would be something like

- node/add/product-display

Comment: Yeah, I'd likely do something more like Kickstart 2.x does where the menu item is for adding a product display with an inline entity form facilitating the creation of products along with the nodes.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I've added some additional info for adding a link to create a product display. An inline entity form could potentially follow on from that. Cheers.